Картинка в подписи Outlook 365 не отображается
Есть код, который делает рассылку. На MS Office 2021 все работало, а теперь Office 365 и как итог, картинка в подписи не отображается (просто пустое пятно в письме).
    import codecs
    # below is the coding logic for signature
    sig_files_path = 'AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Signatures\\' + 'signature (... account name)' + '_files\\'
    sig_html_path = 'AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Signatures\\' + 'signature (... account name)' + '.htm'

    signature_path = os.path.join((os.environ['USERPROFILE']), sig_files_path)
    html_doc = os.path.join((os.environ['USERPROFILE']), sig_html_path)
    html_doc = html_doc.replace('\\\\', '\\')

    html_file = codecs.open(html_doc, 'r', errors='ignore')
    signature_code = html_file.read()

    signature_code = signature_code.replace(('signature (... account name)' + '_files/'), signature_path)
    html_file.close()
    
    
    new_path = main_report_new_path + "\\Daily_Report_" + str(report_day) + ".xlsb"
    
    office = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    office.Visible = True
    office.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb = office.Workbooks.Open(Final_Report_file)
    wb.SaveAs(Filename=new_path)
    wb.Close(True)
    office.Quit()
    
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    # mail.To = '....'
    mail.To = .... (тут адреса)
    mail.Subject = f'Daily Sales Report _ {report_day}'
    
    message = """<html><body> 
                        <font face= 'Segoe UI' size='2' color='#191970'> 
                        Привет, коллеги! <br> 
                        Во вложении обновленный отчет. <br> 
                        <br>
                        <br> 
                        </body></html>  """
    
    mail.Display()
    mail.HTMLBody = message + signature_code
    mail.Attachments.Add(new_path)
    mail.Send()

